# Dúvidas com a classe ConnectionFactory e DAO

Tags: java, conexão

Quero fazer um **crud** simples estou me baseando em algumas classes prontas. A minha dúvida segue:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

private String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/aluno";
private String user = "postgres";
private String password = "";

public Connection getConnection(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
```

Essa parte:

```
return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

Quer dizer que a `DriverManager` possui o método estático chamado `getConnection`? E o que ele retorna? Uma conexão?

E tive dúvida com essa parte também:

```
public AlunoDAO(){
    if(connection == null){
        connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
    }
}
```

Estou acessando o método da classe `ConnectionFactory` logo no construtor, como se chama fazer esse tipo de coisa?

Por que não foi feito assim:

```
connection.getConnection()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Quer dizer que a DriverManager possui o método estático chamado
>   getConnection? E o que ele retorna? Uma conexão?

Exatamente. O método `getConnection` é estático e vai retornar uma conexão (uma instância de `java.sql.Connection`) de acordo com os parâmetros de configuração que foram especificados.

Note que, no seu caso, você está conectando no PostgreSQL. Para isso, você precisa da biblioteca de conexão com esse banco de dados (geralmente um aquivo *.jar que deve estar no seu classpath quando você iniciar a aplicação). É nesse jar que estará a implementação de como conectar com o PostgreSQL.

O Java tem uma abstração para conexão em banco de dados que se chama [JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html) (Java Database Connectivity). O driver do PostgreSQL que você está usando segue a especificação dessa abstração para implementar os detalhes de conexão com um banco PostgreSQL.

E qual a importância disso?

Amanhã se você alterar o seu banco de dados para MySQL, por exemplo, bastará incluir o jar (driver de conexão com MySQL) e alterar a string de conexão para o MySQL. Obviamente, se você estiver usando recursos específicos do PostgreSQL dentro das suas classes DAO, então a alteração será mais complicada. Essa é uma das razões de frameworks como o Hibernate existir, mas isso é assunto pra outra pergunta.

Agora sobre o DAO...

> Estou acessando o método da classe ConnectionFactory logo no
>   construtor, como se chama fazer esse tipo de coisa?

No seu DAO existe um atributo que se chama `java.sql.Connection connection`. Esse atributo é o que você usará para interagir com o seu banco de dados. Fazendo consultas, inserções, alterações, etc.

Quando você instancia um AlunoDAO, esse atributo é inicializado com `null`. Entretanto, logo no seu construtor você passa pra ele a referência de um objeto `Connection`, criado pela sua fábrica chamada `ConnectionFactory`. Em outras palavras, a instância do seu AlunoDAO tem agora uma conexão com o banco de dados.

Se você fizer somente isso `connection.getConnection()`, como proposto na pergunta, haverá um erro de compilação. Já que a classe `java.sql.Connection` não possui um método `getConnection()`. Quem tem um `getConnection()` é o `DriverManager`.

No geral, sua implementação está coerente. A única ressalva que faço é que cada vez que você chamar `ConnectionFactory.getConnection()` uma nova conexão com o banco de dados será feita. Isso não é desejável, pois cada que vez que você instanciar um dos seus DAOs, uma nova conexão será realizada sem necessidade. Geralmente, você trabalha com uma conexão ou usa alguma biblioteca para gerenciar um pool de conexões. Mas isso é assunto para outra pergunta.

Comment: Obrigada. " Obviamente, se você estiver usando recursos específicos do PostgreSQL dentro das suas classes DAO, então a alteração será mais complicada." Tu se refere a sintaxe do banco de dados, não é?

Comment: Você sabe muito! uau :D

Comment: Isso mesmo @AlineGonzaga. A sintaxe SQL básica é geralmente a mesma, pois as empresas que desenvolvem os bancos procuram seguir um padrão, entretanto, tem coisas que podem divergir muito. Exemplo: no SQL Server consulta-se a data atual do banco com a funcao getdate(), já no PostgreSQL a função é outra. Assim, se você usa este tipo de coisa específica (e existem muitas), acaba que alterar o código para adaptar para outro banco pode ser um pouco trabalhoso.